# How to count number of checked Checkboxes with different "Name" attributes?

Tags: php, forms

I have fieldset with multiple checkboxes for a MySQL insert from a form.

```
<fieldset id="my_checkboxes"> 

        <legend>My Checkboxes (Select at least 2)</legend> 

        <label for="checkbox1"> 
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="yes" name="the_checkbox" /> 
            CheckBox #1
        </label> 

        <label for="checkbox2"> 
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="yes" name="the_checkbox2" /> 
            CheckBox #2
        </label> 

    </fieldset>
```

I need to be able to have each checkbox have a unique NAME attribute because each checkbox inserts data into it's own column in the database.  (Otherwise, i would just use the `the_checkbox[]` as the name for each).

My problem is I need to have the user select at least 2 checkboxes in order to submit the form.  Since I have seperate names for each, I cannot use the following code anymore as it counts by name:

```
$checkboxcount = count($_POST['the_checkbox']);
if($checkboxcount < 1)
{
    $errors[] = $checkboxcount;
}
```

MY SQL statement looks like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table(the_checkbox,the_checkbox2) values 
(
'".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['the_checkbox']))."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['the_checkbox2']))."'
)";
```

What would you suggest for me to either A. Count checkboxes even with seperate Names, or B. keep the same name but somehow insert data into MySQL as seperate column names?

Comment: What does your SQL statement look like?

Comment: Edited the question with the SQL statement.

Comment: First, you should accept Michael's answer as it correctly fits your requirement. Second, you should NOT use REQUEST like in your code. Rather, you should take the values into a second variable only if the checkbox is checked. Otherwise you're going to have issues on some servers. This is because only the CHECKED boxes are posted to the form. +1 for Michael

Comment: Instead of REQUEST, should I use POST?   I'm confused, as my code is working perfectly as is.   I'm using validation for the count so that the form won't be processed if there is no selection.Could you show me a barebones example of what you mean?

Comment: To answer it that way, yes, POST is better than REQUEST... But that's not the point. The checkbox's values ONLY reach the server if you check it. So you should first check if it's set, then build the SQL string based on that. Looks like you're new to SQL. But as times goes on you'll learn why. This comment box is a little too small to give you an explanations. If you'd like to learn concepts of coding there are many tutorials out there. Take the time and go through them. And IF you're interested, I upload some YouTube videos explaining a few things at my channel 'marhaonline'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer to keep different names, then do something like this:

```
$chkbox_count = 0;
if (isset($_POST['the_checkbox']) && $_POST['the_checkbox'] == "yes") $chkbox_count++;
if (isset($_POST['the_checkbox2']) && $_POST['the_checkbox'] == "yes") $chkbox_count++;
// etc...
```

I would usually prefer to use use the same name for a related group of checkboxes though, with different values, but the way you are handing them directly into a SQL string makes your method of different names a little easier to handle.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks that works great.  Now I just have to make sure I can still validate this on the jQuery side with the Validate plugin.

Comment: your answer IS correct. But I think it's not necessary to to check for the value 'yes', since only the checked boxes reach the server. So using just isset, is sufficient.